# Wordpress on XAMPP setting up Zoho mail

Tags: wordpress, xampp, zoho, sendmail.exe

A wordpress website running on XAMPP which is accessible from the internet. Now since i only have a domain name and not a service with emails included I've setup my email under zoho.com...

Send emails from a email address to the setup address at zoho.com works just fine... Now comes the problem:

When I try to use a contact form on wordpress (Which is running on xampp) it fails to work.

I have adjusted my sendmail.ini and php.ini with the following:

In php.ini:

```
SMTP = smtp.zoho.com
smtp_port = 465

sendmail_path = "\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t" // This was commented with a ; in front and i uncommented it.

; sendmail_path="C:\xampp\mailtodisk\mailtodisk.exe" // This was uncommented (did not have the ;) i commented it otherwise it would safe the mails on the drive
```

in sendmail.ini i adjusted the following:

```
smtp_server= smtp.zoho.com
smtp_port=465
smtp_ssl=ssl
error_logfile=error.log
debug_logfile=debug.log
auth_username=bla@mydomain.com // This is adjusted to dummydata in this post.
auth_password=mypassword  // This is adjusted to dummydata in this post.
```

However i still get a crash file when i try the contact form saying the following:

```
(deleted some data out of here, which had nothing to do with the error, such as my pc name and my language etc etc.)

display mode      : 1920x1080, 32 bit
process id        : $c48
allocated memory  : 26,24 MB
command line      : "C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe" -t
executable        : sendmail.exe
exec. date/time   : 2011-06-18 01:10
compiled with     : Delphi 2006/07
madExcept version : 3.0l
callstack crc     : $1d5da2f6, $4f4b1b87, $4f4b1b87
exception number  : 1
exception class   : EIdSocketError
exception message : Socket Error # 10060 Connection timed out.

    main thread ($1ac4):
    00435e23 +0073 sendmail.exe IdStack                         706  +42 TIdStack.RaiseSocketError
    00435daa +0016 sendmail.exe IdStack                         660   +1 TIdStack.RaiseLastSocketError
    0045f2e8 +0100 sendmail.exe IdSSLOpenSSLHeaders           16464  +22 EIdOpenSSLAPISSLError.RaiseExceptionCode
    0045f1d9 +0021 sendmail.exe IdSSLOpenSSLHeaders           16433   +1 EIdOpenSSLAPISSLError.RaiseException
    00466686 +012a sendmail.exe IdSSLOpenSSL                   2668  +17 TIdSSLSocket.Connect
    00465a1c +00dc sendmail.exe IdSSLOpenSSL                   2262  +21 TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.OpenEncodedConnection
    004655f6 +0062 sendmail.exe IdSSLOpenSSL                   2106   +9 TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.StartSSL
    00465587 +006b sendmail.exe IdSSLOpenSSL                   2093  +15 TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.ConnectClient
    00444a9f +0063 sendmail.exe IdIOHandlerSocket               335  +13 TIdIOHandlerSocket.Open
    00465637 +0007 sendmail.exe IdSSLOpenSSL                   2122   +1 TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Open
    0044157d +0235 sendmail.exe IdTCPClient                     318  +53 TIdTCPClientCustom.Connect
    00445cc8 +00a4 sendmail.exe IdExplicitTLSClientServerBase   257  +23 TIdExplicitTLSClient.Connect
    0045ab7b +0017 sendmail.exe IdSMTP                          373   +2 TIdSMTP.Connect
    004b5f14 +1060 sendmail.exe sendmail                        808 +326 initialization
    7773919d +000c KERNEL32.DLL                                          BaseThreadInitThunk
    
    stack dump:
    0018fbac  28 5e 43 00 de fa ed 0e - 01 00 00 00 07 00 00 00  (^C.............
    0018fbbc  c0 fb 18 00 28 5e 43 00 - 80 cc 1d 02 ec 28 43 00  ....(^C......(C.
    0018fbcc  c0 3f 46 00 78 1d 1f 02 - fc fb 18 00 dc fb 18 00  .?F.x...........
    0018fbdc  10 fc 18 00 c8 4b 40 00 - fc fb 18 00 05 00 00 00  .....K@.........
    0018fbec  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 4c 27 00 00 30 50 1d 02  ........L'..0P..
    0018fbfc  08 fc 18 00 ad 5d 43 00 - 30 50 1d 02 f0 fc 18 00  .....]C.0P......
    0018fc0c  ed f2 45 00 14 fd 18 00 - c8 4b 40 00 f0 fc 18 00  ..E......K@.....
    0018fc1c  f8 38 82 03 ff ff ff ff - c0 3f 46 00 00 00 00 00  .8.......?F.....
    0018fc2c  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
    0018fc3c  eb 61 ce 7c c0 f6 82 03 - e7 6c 74 c9 6f e6 00 12  .a.|.....lt.o...
    0018fc4c  e0 fa 82 03 20 11 00 00 - f8 38 82 03 f7 ec 00 12  .........8......
    0018fc5c  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - e0 fa 82 03 06 00 00 00  ................
    0018fc6c  01 00 00 00 58 37 82 03 - f9 27 04 11 00 f3 03 12  ....X7...'......
    0018fc7c  4b 6b 74 c9 38 fa 00 12 - f8 38 82 03 16 00 00 00  Kkt.8....8......
    0018fc8c  e0 fa 82 03 04 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
    0018fc9c  f8 38 82 03 00 00 00 00 - f8 38 82 03 ce 86 00 12  .8.......8......
    0018fcac  f8 38 82 03 20 11 00 00 - 21 11 00 00 ff ff ff ff  .8......!.......
    0018fcbc  20 4e 00 00 d4 fc 18 00 - 20 11 00 00 00 00 00 00  .N..............
    0018fccc  00 00 00 00 ff ff ff ff - ad d5 01 12 a0 3a 82 03  .............:..
    0018fcdc  04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - ff ff ff ff 00 00 00 00  ................
    
    disassembling:
    [...]
    00435e13       push    eax
    00435e14       mov     ecx, [ebp-8]
    00435e17       mov     dl, 1
    00435e19       mov     eax, [$4352ac]
    00435e1e       call    -$717 ($43570c)        ; IdStack.EIdSocketError.CreateError
    00435e23     > call    -$3113c ($404cec)      ; System.@RaiseExcept
    00435e28 707   xor     eax, eax
    00435e2a       pop     edx
    00435e2b       pop     ecx
    00435e2c       pop     ecx
    00435e2d       mov     fs:[eax], edx
    [...]
```

Comment: Sendmail is not able to connect to zoho mail on port 465. Check if the port is open in firewall.

Comment: i fixed the issue. It is very well possible. But its kind of glitchy, ended up using a wordpress plugin, which fixed the issue. Used that instead, since the other thing is messed up.